# Different Object Library In Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

[image: Different object library]

Notice the object library in the attached screen shot, at the right bottom.

It's different to the usual one I'm used to work on, I clicked to open an XIB and it was gone and I don't know how to get this one back. Is it even useful ?

I scrolled through it and found many more controls like Bevel Button, Secure Text Field....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are elements for OSX. Xcode seems to to know that this is an iOS project if no Interface Builder file is opened. If you open the Interface Builder, Xcode realizes that this is an iOS project and only shows iOS elements.

Comment: Indeed; the library is context-specific.

Comment: I see then where this is coming from. Rookie question but thank you.